# Given the function $f$ such that $\int_x^{a+x}f(t)dt=3$, check a set of properties of the function $f$.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\int_x^{a+x} f(t)dt = 3, \hspace{.3cm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have to check if the function $f$ is periodic, injective, surjective and bounded.

I am half-way there. I think. First I took the derivative on both sides of the given relation:

$$\bigg( \int_x^{a+x} f(t)dt \bigg )' = (3)'$$

$$f(a+x)-f(x)=0$$

$$f(a+x)=f(x)$$

So that means that the function is periodic, with the period of $T=a$. Also, since the function is periodic, it means that it cannot be injective. I think my reasoning is correct so far, however I don't know how to check the surjectivity and if the function is bounded or not.

Comment: I think $f$ needs to be neither bounded nor surjective as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794766/is-every-1-periodic-function-integrable-on-0-1-bounded) and $\lvert\sin(x)\vert$ show

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I think periodicity is also not guaranteed unless $f$ is continuous. The argument of OP fails without continuity. I have posted a partial answer assuming continuity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in the question. You should have $\int_x^{a+x} $ instead of $\int_a^{a+x}$. If it is $\int_a^{a+x}$ we get a contradiction by letting $x \to 0$.

For your argument to work you have to assume that $f$ is continuous. (Without continuity we cannot even differentiate the equation and prove periodicity). So **I will assume that $f$ is continuous**. Any continuous periodic function is bounded and a bounded function cannot be surjective. That answers all  the questions.

PS: It is easy to construct an example where $f$ is not periodic. Just alter the values at integer multiples if $a$. (The value of the integral does not change).

Comment: Why is it that any continuous periodic function is bounded? Is there some sort of proof? Or logical, intuitive explanation?

Comment: Suppose $f$ has period $a$.  Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,a]$, which is compact, $f$ is bounded on $[0,a]$.  Also, by periodicity, every value of $f$ is the same as some value of $f$ on $[0,a]$.